# Remove Y label on point

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How to remove the Y value on the circle point?
Or just change the color to white.

[image]

```
val lineData = LineData(dataSet)
        chart.setNoDataText("Nenhum treino computado")
        chart.setDrawBorders(false)
        chart.data = lineData
        chart.description = desc
        chart.setGridBackgroundColor(R.color.graphGride)
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
        chart.legend.textColor = ActivityCompat.getColor(this, R.color.graphLabel)
        chart.axisLeft.gridColor = ActivityCompat.getColor(this, R.color.graphLabel)
        chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        chart.xAxis.textColor = ActivityCompat.getColor(this, R.color.graphLabel)
        chart.xAxis.axisLineColor = ActivityCompat.getColor(this, R.color.graphLabel)
        chart.xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the values :

```
dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
```

To change the color :

```
dataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```